# pandas table.loc lambda function failing to slice table based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am running code in python2.7 that looks like this:

```
def selectSignificant(table, pvalue, limit):
    """Return significant peaks over a limit"""
    table_pvalue       = table.loc[lambda df: df.pval_gamma_adj < pvalue,:]
    table_pvalue_limit = table_pvalue.loc[lambda df: df.SPC > limit,:]
    table_pvalue_limit.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return table_pvalue_limit
```

It is failing at the point of calling the lambda function, which for my little understanding of pandas, seems to be taking a slice of `table` based on the values of `pval_gamma_adj` being smaller than `pvalue`.

When I run this with an example dataset in the package, it enters this function with a `table` of `[2012 rows x 5 columns]`, a `pvalue` of `0.0004970178926441351` and a `limit` of `11`. When calling the first lambda statement, the error is:

```
p table.loc[lambda df: df.pval_gamma_adj < pvalue,:]
*** KeyError: KeyError('the label [<function <lambda> at 0x7ff5aa896500>] is not in the [index]',)
```

which makes me wonder if calling the lambda function returns something not expected by `table.loc`. I can see how applying the simple condition below returns some `True` and `False` values:

```
(Pdb) p table.pval_gamma_adj < pvalue
0        True
1       False
[...]
2010    False
2011    False
Name: pval_gamma_adj, dtype: bool
```

So my guess is that using lambda here, for whatever reason under the conditions of where I am running it (Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.12), is giving an error.

Any ideas on how to solve this? These are the two only lambda calls in the entire code, how can I turn them into a similar statement that does not cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solution should be simplify with no `lambda` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
def selectSignificant(table, pvalue, limit):
    """Return significant peaks over a limit"""
    table_pvalue       = table[table.pval_gamma_adj < pvalue]
    table_pvalue_limit = table_pvalue[table_pvalue.SPC > limit]
    table_pvalue_limit.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return table_pvalue_limit
```

---

In your function is used [selection by callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-callable), maybe reason for errors is pandas version under 0.18.1

Comment: I changed the code as described in this solution by @jezrael and got it to work. Thanks.